# Vishvarupa nomenclature

Tags: vishnu

Is there any distinctive nomenclature when depicting the expanding form of visnu compared with the transcending form?  Is [visvarupa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishvarupa) vestige the expanding form only?  then what is the transcending form referred to as?

also where/whom is the divine eye in the visvarupa (either) case?

Comment: What do you mean by Expanding form vs transcending form?

Comment: @Adiyarkku i'm not totally sure, but the art is showing there to be what appears to be a transcending form (vertical), and also depicting an expanding version (horizontal)

Comment: The usually description of Vishvarupa is such that it encompasses everything, horizontal vertical oblique directions, everything. That’s why it’s called as Vishvarupa. Gods form is not an image which can be plotted on an X axis and Y axis and say okay in expanding he went to this coordinate, in transcending he went up to this coordinate. He has thousand heads, thousand arms, all the devatas, asuras, Naga, Yaksha, gandharva, kinnara mountain, stars, planets, fire water air sky upper worlds lower worlds, all rest in him. He’s vishvarupa.

Comment: @Adiyarkku ok i see...thx..i was believing the art too much!

Comment: @Adiyarkku by vertical i perhaps meant the departure of visnu avatar, passing through the brahma loka, returning to vaikunta adobe or something like that..is there a term for that?